# Why is UIAppearance not working in applicationWillEnterForeground

Tags: ios, uiapplicationdelegate, uiappearance

I am trying to implement different themes to my application. The user can select the different themes in the Settingsbundle, then the application should display the theme according to the user decision.

I call the theming method in `applicationWillEnterForeground`, but then nothing will change. When I set the theming code in `- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions` It only themes my application the first time i launch it, every other launch it wont change anything.

I cant disable the background mode, cause then my application wont work. Any idea, how I can call the theming method without crashing my app?

Here is my theming code which should be called **every time the application entered the foreground**:

```
-(void)themeDecicion {

    NSUserDefaults *defaults = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
    NSInteger themeMode = [defaults integerForKey:@"themeMode"];
    if (themeMode == 0) {
        themeMode = 1;
    }

    if (themeMode == 1) {
        NSLog(@"automatically");
        NSString *colorString = [DeviceColor frontColor];
        if ([colorString isEqualToString:@"Black"]) {
            [self blackTheme];
        } else if ([colorString isEqualToString:@"White"]) {
            [self whiteTheme];
        } else {
            [self blackTheme];
        }
    } else if (themeMode == 2) {
        [self blackTheme];

    } else if (themeMode == 3) {
        [self whiteTheme];
    } else {
        [self blackTheme];
    }

}

-(void)blackTheme {

    [[UITabBar appearance] setTintColor:[UIColor whiteColor]];
    [[UITabBar appearance] setBarStyle:UIBarStyleBlack];
    [[UINavigationBar appearance] setTintColor:[UIColor whiteColor]];
    [[UINavigationBar appearance] setBarStyle:UIBarStyleBlackTranslucent];
    [[UISearchBar appearance] setBarStyle:UIBarStyleDefault];
}

-(void)whiteTheme {

    UIColor *defaultColor = [UIColor colorWithRed:(21/255.0) green:(121/255.0) blue:(251/255.0) alpha:1];

    [[UITabBar appearance] setTintColor:defaultColor];
    [[UITabBar appearance] setBarStyle:UIBarStyleDefault];
    [[UINavigationBar appearance] setTintColor:defaultColor];
    [[UINavigationBar appearance] setBarStyle:UIBarStyleDefault];
    [[UISearchBar appearance] setBarStyle:UIBarStyleDefault];

}
```

Comment: You don't provide any useful details. Show the relevant code. Provide specific details about the crash. No one can help with what you have provided so far.

Comment: @rmaddy ok, sorry, I provided wrong informations. I added some code.

Comment: You should provide information about the crash too.

Comment: @GabrielePetronella there isnt a crash with this code

Comment: Keep in mind that the appearance proxies have no affect on existing UI widgets, only new ones. When entering the foreground you will also need to set the colors and styles of existing tab bars, nav bars, and search bars.

Comment: Read my answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17070582/using-uiappearance-and-switching-themes/17080101#17080101