# Separating UIAppearence code

Tags: ios, themes, uinavigationbar, uicolor, uiappearance

I want to implement add themes to an app I'm creating. Simply just switching between 2 colors and I want the navigation bars, tool bars etc. to appear in the selected color.

When the app first loads, I apply one color to in the `didFinishLaunchingWithOptions` method in the AppDelegate.

```
UIColor *blueTheme = [UIColor colorWithRed:80/255.0f green:192/255.0f blue:224/255.0f alpha:1.0f];
UIColor *pinkTheme = [UIColor colorWithRed:225/255.0f green:87/255.0f blue:150/255.0f alpha:1.0f];

[[UINavigationBar appearance] setBarTintColor:pinkTheme];
[[UIToolbar appearance] setBarTintColor:pinkTheme];

[[UINavigationBar appearance] setTintColor:[UIColor whiteColor]];
```

And in the first view controller I have put a segmented control to switch the colors.

```
- (IBAction)themeChosen:(UISegmentedControl *)sender
{
    if (sender.selectedSegmentIndex == 0) {
        UIColor *blueTheme = [UIColor colorWithRed:80/255.0f green:192/255.0f blue:224/255.0f alpha:1.0f];

        [[UINavigationBar appearance] setBarTintColor:blueTheme];
        [[UIToolbar appearance] setBarTintColor:blueTheme];
    } else {
        UIColor *pinkTheme = [UIColor colorWithRed:225/255.0f green:87/255.0f blue:150/255.0f alpha:1.0f];

        [[UINavigationBar appearance] setBarTintColor:pinkTheme];
        [[UIToolbar appearance] setBarTintColor:pinkTheme];
    }
    [[UINavigationBar appearance] setTintColor:[UIColor whiteColor]];
}
```

Say the default theme is pink. I switch to blue from the segmented control and push to the next view controller where there is a `UIToolBar` as well. The newly chosen color(blue) is applied only to the `UIToolBar` but not to the `UINavigationBar`.

Is there a better way to go about this? Also I'd like to put the code related to themes in a separate class because it repeats a lot of code. How do I do that?

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem you're having is due to the fact that `UIAppearance` only takes effect the *next time* a UI control is created. Your new `UIToolbar` takes on the new appearance because when you push a new viewcontroller it has a brand new toolbar. Your `UINavigationBar` is not changing, because it was created when your navigationcontroller's view was created, and won't update its appearance.

You'll have to also update the property directly on your navigationController's navigationBar. e.g.:

```
self.navigationController.navigationBar.barTintColor = blueTheme;
```