# Suggestions needed for application dark mode ios

Tags: ios, objective-c

I am making a dark mode setting for my app.

Currently, the dark mode is nearly working on a single scene. While adding the dark mode though, I noticed that I need a lot of IBOutletCollection to properly change the colors that I want (ex. labels should become white, background black, the title should be a very dark gray...).

Now, this seems inefficient and time consuming. Isn't there a way to load everything, `for()` it, and set the correct color for each specific object? (If there is, how?)

Answer (score 0):

**UIAppearance** is what you are looking for, it’s meant to be used for changing the appearance of a class https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uiappearance?language=objc

For example a label would be styled like this:

```
[[UILabel appearance] setTextColor: [UIColor whiteColor]];
```

See also related question on how to do the actual switching of the themes [Using UIAppearance and switching themes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17070582/using-uiappearance-and-switching-themes)